# How to make my div clickable only once in react Tic Tac Toe game?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to mae a tic tac toe game using react. But I am unable to  achieve the logic of button being clicable only once. Need some help. Here is the code:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'


let data = ["","","","","","","","",""]



const Board = () => {

    let [count, setCount] = useState (0)
    const [allow,  setAllow] = useState(false)
    const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false)

    const title = useRef("")


    const toggler  = (e, index) =>{
        if (allow){
            return 0
        }
        if (count % 2 === 0){
            e.target.innerHTML="<h1>X</h1>"
            data[index]="x"
            setCount(++count)
           
        }
        else{
            e.target.innerHTML="<h1>O</h1>"
            data[index]="o"
            setCount(++count)
            
        }

        if (index === 0){
            setClicked(true)
        }
        else if (index === 2){
            setClicked(true)
        }




        
        
        if (data[0]===data[1] && data[1]===data[2] && data[2]!==""){
            won(data[2])
         }
         else if (data[3]===data[4] && data[4]===data[5] && data[5]!==""){
            won(data[5])
         }
         else if (data[6]===data[7] && data[7]===data[8] && data[8]!==""){
            won(data[8])
         }
         else if (data[0]===data[3] && data[3]===data[6] && data[6]!==""){
            won(data[6])
         }
         else if (data[1]===data[4] && data[4]===data[7] && data[7]!==""){
            won(data[7])
         }
         else if (data[2]===data[5] && data[5]===data[8] && data[8]!==""){
            won(data[8])
         }
         else if (data[0]===data[4] && data[4]===data[8] && data[8]!==""){
            won(data[8])
         }
         else if (data[2]===data[4] && data[4]===data[6] && data[6]!==""){
            won(data[6])
         }
    }

    const won=(winner)=>{
        setAllow(true)
        if (winner === "x"){
            title.current.innerHTML="Congrats X won"
        }
        else if (winner === "o"){
            title.current.innerHTML="Congrats O won"
        }
        else if (count===9){
            title.current.innerHTML="It's a draw"
        }

    }

    // const  checkWinner = () => {
        
    // }

  return (
    <>  
    <h1 ref={title}>Welcome to the Game</h1>

    <div className='column'>
        <div className="row" onClick={!clicked?((e)=>{toggler(e,0)}):null}></div>
        <div className="row" onClick={!clicked?((e)=>{toggler(e,1)}):null}></div>
        <div className="row" onClick={!clicked?((e)=>{toggler(e,2)}):null}></div>
    </div>
    <div className='column'>
        <div className="row" onClick={!clicked?((e)=>{toggler(e,3)}):null}></div>
        <div className="row" onClick={!clicked?((e)=>{toggler(e,4)}):null}></div>
        <div className="row" onClick={!clicked?((e)=>{toggler(e,5)}):null}></div>
    </div>
    <div className='column'>
        <div className="row" onClick={!clicked?((e)=>{toggler(e,6)}):null}></div>
        <div className="row" onClick={!clicked?((e)=>{toggler(e,7)}):null}></div>
        <div className="row" onClick={!clicked?((e)=>{toggler(e,8)}):null}></div>
    </div>

    </>

  )
}

export default Board
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).